# linq query for dictionary obj

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a dictionary object `Dictionary<SomeEnumType, object>`.

```
enum SomeEnumType
{
AType=1,
BType=2,
CType=3
}
```

object will be a collection of `A,B`.

```
public class C {public string Name {get;set;}}
public class A: C { public string prop1 {get;set;}}
public class B: C { public string prop2 {get;set;}}
```

Dictionary object will have entries like below:

```
Dictionary<SomeEnumType, object> dicobj= new Dictionary<SomeEnumType, object>();
dicobj.Add(SomeEnumType.AType, List<A>);
dicobj.Add(SomeEnumType.BType, List<B>);
```

I need to query the Dictionary for `name` and get the object (A or B). For ex. Name="John".

Comment: Your question would be a *lot* clearer if you'd give some sample code which populates the collections.

Comment: `Collection of A` is a `List<A>`?

Comment: @Jon - Did you mean to populate the A, B collections? A, B can List<A>, List<B>.

Comment: @stech: I mean the whole thing. If you can give us a complete program with *all but the bit you don't know how to do* (and the expected results of that) it would make it much simpler.

Comment: Do you mean that the final query should return the dicobj whose collection contains an item with Name John ?

Comment: I hope this isn't a real-life situation.

Comment: @code4life: Do you have a better way to design this obj/collection? Btw, this IS real-time.

Answer (score 0):

All of your special collection are deriving from the same base type, so you could simply iterate over all collections and cast the object to type C:

```
dictObj.Values.OfType<ICollection>()
              .SelectMany(collection => collection.OfType<C>())
              .Where(itemOfTypeC => itemOfTypeC.Name == "John");
```